# How to refresh a data variable post an Ajax call when using Vue.js without resorting v-if directives?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently, I do `v-if="Object.keys(video).length > 0"` on a `div` to ensure that the `video` only gets sent to the `video-player` component when it is actually available.

If I omit the `v-if` check, the `video`, initialized as `null` gets sent to the `video-player` component and the video won't load, even though a second later, the `video` data is populated with a URL from an Ajax call. Is there a better way do solve this issue without resolving to `v-if` directives all over the place?

Comment: Don't instantiate the Vue before your video is available? It's difficult to say with limited information.

Comment: why not check whether the video is null inside `video-player` component? so at parent, you don't need v-if for each video-player component.

Comment: I second @Sphinx. The `<video-player>` component should be the one that handles (or should "worry" about, if you want to humanise it) the `video` values. The parent component simply passes `video` in without checking, from the standpoint that it does not "consume" that data/prop itself. The final consumer of the data/prop should dictate the parsing strategy.

Comment: Code examples would help.

Comment: Good point guys. I'll check out what Sphinx and Terry pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components), it allows you to handle asynchronous code and resolve your component only when is ready, also provides advance features for loading and handle errors, here is a simple example:

```
Vue.component('async-component',
  function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      this.authors = data.results || [];    
      resolve({
        template:
        `
          <div>
            <img 
              v-for="author in authors"
              :src='author.picture.medium' 
            />
          </div>
                `,
        data() {
            authors: []
        }
      });
    });
}); 


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: 
  `
    <async-component />
  `
});
```

You can also check the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ricardoorellana/ksvjwzx5/6/).

Comment: Cool idea but an overkill as I am already using a third party component.

Comment: Probably you may wrap the third party component in your own component a simple one that only resolve the third pary component when the video is ready.

Comment: This works for some cases, but there are times when I have to do it like this because otherwise `retrieveVideoCardCover` throws up. `<video-header v-if="Object.keys(video).length > 0" @played="react" :image="retrieveVideoCardCover(video, 'workout')" :video="video.video">`